# Connect to previous SSH device without having their IP

Tags: linux, bash, networking, ssh

So, it's a very long story, but I'm having to connect from my NAS to my main PC in an SSH connection to play an audio file -- but the IPs aren't static, and I couldn't figure out how to get that working well on Linux... So I either need to find *out* the IP of the opposing computer to SSH, or use SSH itself to connect to the device rather than anything else -- I'm unsure of the best approach. What do you guys think would be the easiest solution here? My NAS is connected to my main Host PC thru ethernet, as follows: PC <-> switch <-> NAS, and there's no other connections on the ethernet connection, if that helps.

I've tried making the IPs static, but they won't connect to eachother when they do. I have a handy dandy kvm here to try to get it working before Barrier is up, but.. It never really worked for some reason. So if we can make it static, that alone would be preferred -- but I don't have high hopes for that, lol.

Comment: This is way too broad for just about any site in the stack-exchange I know, you might get away with it on [su], but I'd want lots of detail of your network setup - `I've tried making the IPs static, but they won't connect to eachother when they do.`  doesn't give people anything to work with.

Comment: I agree, this would be a massive list of troubleshooting options. i.e. Try 1, 2, 3, etc., and see what sticks. Maybe break it down into something smaller, or try to solve it yourself and post the solution here.